# MySql where clause, variable with <> and without comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

When i referring a where clause i saw a code

```
where status='locked'
and =person_uuid.p_uuid
and users.p_uuid <> 1
order by full_name,users.p_uuid
```

I confused with unfamiliar syntax of the code.

- In where clause there is a variable called person_uuid.p_uuid without any comparison.
- users.p_uuid <> 1

I referred some books and websites. but no solution.

is this valid. if so, what's the meaning of that.

Comment: what is between `and` and `=person_uuid.p_uuid`? I am sure something is missing there.

Comment: `users.p_uuid <> 1` means p_uuid is `not equal 1`. That's it

Comment: Are you sure it is not `and person_uuid=p_uuid` ?

Comment: "and =person_uuid.p_uuid":
i agree with above comments,the above code doesnot make any sense,its syntactically wrong.

Comment: @Eternal-Learner, this is from a standard well known project.They have written like that. thanks anyway.

Comment: person_uuid is a table. p_uuid is a column in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,

```
=person_uuid.p_uuid
```

// there should be value to that column, otherwise it will give error

```
users.p_uuid <> 1
```

// implies users.p_uuid not equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full query,
Some RDBMS have a structure where, the select query selected vales will be directly match,

like in your case

=person_uuid.p_uuid

If the select query is created to select person_id from a table person, it will match the condition as

Select person_id from person where status='locked' and person.person_id = person_uuid.p_uuid and users.p_uuid <> 1 order by full_name,users.p_uuid